# git push data stream erro

Tags: visual-studio, github, github-desktop

I'm a beginner of github and i'm using github desktop to do git push.Here is the things: I have a repository that didn't use for a year. All the files in the repository are simple different vs project which contains my LeetCode solutions. Just one day agao, I start to reuse it and happened that error. Every time I finish one leetcode question and try to commit it. this happends[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9x3A.png). After a few times attempt, I found that how many vs project I added in the repository, how many erro object shows up. I tried onlie possible solutions, and nothing works. Some of the vs project can push successfully but some can't. I don't think they have any different. I'm not sure why this happen.
Then I try to fix this by move all useful files to the new reposrity. I first create a new repository. Then I copy the "Solutions" folder (only useful folder of this repository) from the old repository and paste it to new repository. When this is done, I try to commit it. However, the same problems shows up[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3puD.png)
Is there anyone can help fixes this problem and tell me why this will happen, since it's even broken on a new repository.

Comment: Now I can only uploading file directly on github website and pull the rpository down to modify what i want then push it back

Comment: Now what I can do is ignored the folder and push

Comment: I found there is a `Browse.VC.db` casued that problem. Anyone know why? I already added it into the ignore and push it back